# Segmentation fault related to 2 dimn array

Tags: c

I am facing a segmentation error in my code while handling 2d array.. not able to get to where my error lies.. any help is appreciated

here is my code

```
void main()
{
    float32_t buff1d_1[64],buff1d_2[64];
    float32_t buff2d_1[3][64],buff2d_2[3][64];

    fn1(&buff2d_1[0],buff1d_1,buff1d_2,&buff2d_2[0]);
}

void fn1(float32_t** in1,float32_t* out1,float32_t* out2, float32_t** in2)
{
    float32_t trim[3]={0};
    fn2(trim,in1,out1,in2);
}
```

Declaration of fn2 is

```
fn2(float32_t *,float32_t **inputs,float32_t *output, float32_t **coe);
```

The priority of functions are fn2 > fn1 > main.
that is the declaration of fn2 is fixed and i have to change the declaration of fn1 and fn1 call from main accordingly..

Comment: Forget `void main()`. At least it should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: Your code is invalid, `buff1d_1` is declared twice.

Answer (score 2):

`&buff2d_1[0]` and `&buff2d_2[0]` are of type `float32_t (*)[64]` but the function `fn1` expects its first and fourth argument of type `float32_t**`.

Change the function declarator to

```
void fn1(float32_t (*in1)[64],float32_t* out1,float32_t* out2, float32_t (*in2)[64])
```